# Currently running 235 35 R 17 tires. Will 215 45 R17 tires also fit same rims?

Tags: tires, wheels

Are these tire sizes interchangeable for the same set of r8ms?

Answer (score 1):

No.

235/35 has a diameter of 23.8" and a width of 9.6".

215/45 has a diameter of 24.6" and a width of 8.5".

You might be able to get away with 215/40R17 but just buy the proper size for your car. If you're going for a different look, buy different wheels that fit the tire profile you're after.

source - https://tiresize.com/calculator/

Answer (score -1):

Yes, they should work fine, especially on something like a pickup truck.

While the overall wheel diameter will change, it's a fairly insignificant.

The handling may be a bit different however.